# Validação de campos preenchidos de um formulário

Tags: javascript, html5, codeigniter, formulário

Hoje possuo alguns fomulários em janelas (modais) e alguns desses campos preciso obrigar o usuário a preencher hoje estou fazendo da seguinte forma:

Formulário:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso o usuário esqueça de preencher algum campo utilizo o seguinte código onde valido o meu formulário e caso exista algum erro ele retorna uma mensagem:

Codigo:

```
function inserir() {

        $this->template->set('title', 'Inserir Clientes');
        /* Carrega a biblioteca do CodeIgniter responsável pela validação dos formulários */
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        /* Define as tags onde a mensagem de erro será exibida na página */
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<span>', '</span>');

        /* Define as regras para validação */
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('cnome', 'Nome', 'required|max_length[40]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('emailc', 'E-mail', 'trim|required|valid_email|max_length[100]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('contato', 'Contato', 'trim|required|max_length[20]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('telefone', 'Telefone', 'trim|required|max_length[20]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('cidade', 'Cidade', 'trim|required|max_length[60]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('nameR', 'Representante', 'trim|required|max_length[60]');

        /* Executa a validação e caso houver erro chama a função index do controlador */
        if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {

            $this->session->set_flashdata('mensagem', "<div class='alert alert-danger'> preencha todos os campos antes de salvar </div>");
                redirect('clientes');
            /* Senão, caso sucesso: */
        } else {

            /* Recebe os dados do formulário (visão) */
            $data['cnome'] = ucwords($this->input->post('cnome'));
            $data['contato'] = ucwords($this->input->post('contato'));
            $data['telefone'] = $this->input->post('telefone');
            $data['emailc'] = strtolower($this->input->post('emailc'));
            $data['cidade'] = ucwords($this->input->post('cidade'));
            $data['representante'] = ucwords($this->input->post('nameR'));

            /* Chama a função inserir do modelo */
            if ($this->model->inserir($data)) {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('mensagem', "<div class='alert alert-success'> Cliente salvo com sucesso</div>");
                redirect('clientes');
            } else {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('mensagem', "<div class='alert alert-danger'> Erro ao inserir cliente</div>");
                redirect('clientes');
            }

        }
    }
```

Mensagem retornada em caso de erro:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora explicando o que eu procuro fazer, quero deixar o sistema mais funcional hoje se o usuário esquece algum campo ele é retorna a pagina de listagem e necessita abrir a função de cadastrar novamente e informar todos os campos novamente, minha ideia agora é que caso ele esqueça algum campo e clique em salvar o modal não seja fechado e sim que o campo(s) que ele não preencheu sejam realçados em vermelho, para isso acredito que precisarei utilizar javascript,esta é minha duvida.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso pode ser feito por meio do próprio HTML, basta adicionar `required`:

```
<input type="text" name="usrname" required>
```

É uma opção simples e funcional.

Comment: Perfeito amigo funcionou muito bem

Answer (score 1):

Ola, siga os passos e adapte para o seu código para conseguir o efeito que deseja.

> Crie uma função privada para validar o formulário

```
private function form_cliente_insert()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    /* Define as regras para validação */
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cnome', 'Nome', 'required|max_length[40]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('emailc', 'E-mail', 'trim|required|valid_email|max_length[100]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('contato', 'Contato', 'trim|required|max_length[20]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('telefone', 'Telefone', 'trim|required|max_length[20]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cidade', 'Cidade', 'trim|required|max_length[60]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('nameR', 'Representante', 'trim|required|max_length[60]');

    // Vamos precisar retornar o _check_form para saber se vamos reabrir o modal ou não
    $_check_form = $this->form_validation->run();

    if ( $_check_form === FALSE ) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('mensagem', "<div class='alert alert-danger'> preencha todos os campos antes de salvar </div>");
        /* Senão, caso sucesso: */
    } else {

        /* Recebe os dados do formulário (visão) */
        $data['cnome'] = ucwords($this->input->post('cnome'));
        $data['contato'] = ucwords($this->input->post('contato'));
        $data['telefone'] = $this->input->post('telefone');
        $data['emailc'] = strtolower($this->input->post('emailc'));
        $data['cidade'] = ucwords($this->input->post('cidade'));
        $data['representante'] = ucwords($this->input->post('nameR'));

        /* Chama a função inserir do modelo */
        if ($this->model->inserir($data)) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('mensagem', "<div class='alert alert-success'> Cliente salvo com sucesso</div>");
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('mensagem', "<div class='alert alert-danger'> Erro ao inserir cliente</div>");
        }
    }

    return $_check_form;
}
```

> Adicione este código no Controller que gerencia a página clientes

```
// Valor padrão, não mostra o modal
$data['open_modal_cliente'] = false;

if(!empty($_POST))
{
    // Valor negativo pois em caso de sucesso, retorna TRUE
    // Precisamos apenas de quando for FALSE, que é quando não validou e precisamos
    // reabrir o modal. Será necessário enviar este campo para a view..
    $_re_open_modal = !$this->form_cliente_insert();

    $data['open_modal_cliente'] = $_re_open_modal;  
}
```

Na view, coloque o `set_value` com o nome do campo

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="telefone" value="<?php echo set_value('telefone'); ?>" />
```

> No rodapé, verifique se precisa abrir o modal e abra caso seja necessário. O exemplo abaixo supõem que esteja utilizando o modal do bootstrap.

```
<?php if($open_modal_cliente): ?>
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ 
        $('#nome-do-seu-modal').modal({
            keyboard: false,
            backdrop: 'static',
            show: true
        });
    }, false);
</script>
<?php endif ?>
```

O segredo é não utilizar o redirect pois, quando você o utiliza, perde as informações do $_POST. Veja se consegue fazer esta implementação, em caso de dúvida envie-nos. ;)

Answer (score 0):

O ideal seria postar o código do formulário e biblioteca utilizada para que possamos testá-lo.

Mas acredito que comentando  `redirect('clientes');` em

```
  $this->session->set_flashdata('mensagem', "<div class='alert alert-danger'> preencha todos os campos antes de salvar </div>");
  //redirect('clientes');
```

deve resolver seu problema!